# Is there an updated walk through discussing the WindowsWizard file in Revit 2022 SDK? also is forge actually required?

Tags: api, revit-api, forge

I would like to create a Revit add-in that is able to create, modify and produce a window or door that can be loaded into Revit. I would also like to be able to use that information to fill out a window or door schedule. I found the windowWizard in the Revit 2022 SDK that I wanted to study but it seems that the steps to implement it are quite old, as a lot of the steps are no longer needed. I'm curious if there is an updated walkthrough anywhere for the WindowsWizard.

I'm also curious why it seems this is now only possible through Forge. Am I understanding this correctly or is there a way to create a similar addin like the WindowWizard that doesn't require forge?

Comment: Please Read How to Ask a Question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   First

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have handy access to it now, but I think it still works as-is. No Forge is required to run it inside of Revit as an addin. Forge is only required if you want to send a model and the UI inputs to the cloud to be executed…